# How to share text into facebook using default android sharing(intent)?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I am working on text sharing in all default available app like,facebook,gmail..etc.

Here I put snapshot of my code.

```
final Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent1.setAction("https://play.google.com/store");
    emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"https://play.google.com/store");
    emailIntent1.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent1, "send"));
```

My problem is ,I can not share text in facebook.

***Your answer would be appreciated.***

Comment: Refers these link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I don't wann share using facebook sdk.i want to share using intent.

Comment: what is your exact question be specific

Comment: i want to share "https://play.google.com/store" this text into facebook.

Comment: type should be text/plain `emailIntent1.setType("text/plain")`

Comment: do you want to share image along with text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this...**

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share this app");
        String shareMessage = "https://play.google.com/store";
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose the messenger to share this App"));
```

Comment: this one is what he wants I guess.. +1

Comment: it works but only for text.but i also want  share bitmap imageuri.i can't share text with bitmap image.emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will create an Intent Chooser that list out all the installed app on the device that accept type "text/plain".

```
private void share(String text) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share text"));
}
```